# React select dynamically adding options menu list scroll issue

Tags: scroll, react-select, rerender, menu-list

I'm using react-select and I added a button at the end of the MenuList component in order to load more data.
When I click on this button, my state get updated and the `options` props of `Select` changes. This re-render properly the new options, however, the list is scrolled back to its top.

```
const MenuList = (props: MenuListProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <components.MenuList {...props }>
      {props.children}
      <button onClick={fetchMore}>Load more</button>
    </components.MenuList>
  );
};

return <Select
  onFocus={onFocus}
  isLoading={loading}
  isClearable={true}
  isSearchable={true}
  options={items.map(item => {
    return { label: item.name, value: item.id };
  })}
  onInputChange={onInputChange}
  components={{ MenuList }}
/>;
```

So whenever I change my `items` state, the menu list is scrolled back to top. I tried to find a workaround by manually scrolling back to the previous position but it's visible and not satsfying.

Any ideas on how to get around this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding react-virtuoso to the MenuList of the react-select. I used rangeChanged from Virtuoso to save the startIndex in the component state every time I got to the end of the options list and set this index as initialTopMostItemIndex in Virtuoso. It might not be the best solution but it works.

https://virtuoso.dev/virtuoso-api-reference/ -> check initialTopMostItemIndex & rangeChanged

I am also interested in other solutions.